# Protected method call on joomla site

Tags: joomla

I am getting this kind of Joomla error

> Call to protected method JApplicationSite::route() from context ''

not sure how what to do and how to fixed it without breakig site or delete some files. Please help.

Joomla version is 3.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. It seems that that version is not working with php 7.1.4, updated joomla and some modules and it worked. Me being supid.